# react native setState arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

I am using an ImagePicker to select photos from my albums and then display it on screen.

```
this.state = {
pictures:[]
}

takePics(){
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  multiple: true
}).then(response => {

for(var i=0; i < response.length; i++){
  var file = {
      uri : response[i].sourceURL,
      name: response[i].filename,
      type: 'image/png'
  }

  RNS3.put(file, config)
  .then((responseFromS3) => {
    this.setState({pictures:[response[0].sourceURL,
                             response[1].sourceURL,                                                  
                             response[2].sourceURL]})
    })
  }
  })
}

showPhotos(){
<Swiper style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={this.state.showsButtons} showsPagination={this.state.showsPagination} loop={true}>
<View style={styles.slide1}>
<Image
   style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
   source={{uri:this.state.pictures[0]}}/>
</View>
<View style={styles.slide2}>
   <Image
      style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
      source={{uri:this.state.pictures[1]}}/>
</View>
<View style={styles.slide2}>
       <Image
          style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
          source={{uri:this.state.pictures[2]}}/>
</View>
</Swiper>
}
```

The code above works fine. However, the problem is that I have to pre-assign how many photos will be selected.

For example, in the code I preassigned 3 photos, so if I pick less or more than 3 photos, the code won't work.

Since I don't know how many photos the user will select, no matter how many photos the user select, the code should work.

Any suggestions or comments will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is the revised code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, Image, FlatList,StyleSheet,TouchableHighlight,Button} from 'react-native'
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

class ImageSwiper extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      pictures: [],
    }
  }

  takePics = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({multiple: true})
      .then(response => {
        let tempArray = []
        response.forEach((item) => {
          let file = {
            uri: item.sourceURL,
            name: item.filename,
            type: 'image/png'
          }
          tempArray.push(file)
        })
        this.setState({pictures: tempArray})
      })
  }

  takePicHandler(){
    return(
      <View style={{width:375,height:220,backgroundColor:'#F5F5F5'}}>
      <FlatList
           data = {this.state.pictures}
           renderItem = {({item}) =>
             <View style={styles.slide1}>
               <Image
                 style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                 source={{uri:item.uri}}/>
             </View>
           }
         />
      <View style={{marginTop:-26,justifyContent:'flex-end',alignSelf:'flex-end',marginRight:16}}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={this.takePics.bind(this)}>
                <Image
                  style={{width:54,height:54}}
                  source={require('./Components/Assets/camera.png')}/>
            </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      </View>
    )
    console.log(uri)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
      {this.takePicHandler()}
      </View>
)
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  slide1: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  }
})
export default ImageSwiper
```

I tried the code above the error went away but nothing is showing on screen after I select photos. I am also getting a warning `missing keys for items`

Comment: what can you control it using a `state` ?

Comment: please look into `forEach()` or `map()` for `JavaScript`. Btw why are you setting state for all of them in your for loop? Why not just push into a temporary array and set `this.state.pictures` as the temp array after? Most importantly, please look into using a `FlatList`.

Comment: @Harrison Thanks for the comment. I am very new to react, so I might be doing things not properly. If you could show me an example I would really appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `forEach` or `map` function to map through an array and return data.
In addition, use a `FlatList` to display a list of data.

```
import { React } from 'react'
import { View, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native'

export default class Example extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      pictures: [],
    }
  }

  takePics = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({multiple: true})
      .then(response => {
        let tempArray = []
        response.forEach((item) => {
          let image = {
            uri: item.path,
            width: item.width,
            height: item.height,
          }
          tempArray.push(image)
        })
        this.setState({pictures: tempArray})
      })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <FlatList 
          data = {this.state.pictures}
          renderItem = {({item}) => 
            <View style={styles.slide1}>
              <Image
                style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                source={item}/>
            </View>
          }
        />
      </View>
    )}
}
```

Comment: I am getting one error . `JSON value of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to NSString` Does this has to do with `source={{uri:item}}`?

Comment: @kirimi can you describe the data structure you are receiving? for example, `console.log` it. And yes it might have to do with it, see if changing it to `{uri:item.uri}` will fix it. I forgot about that sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the code but for some reason I can't see my selected photos on screen. I have edited my question. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @kirimi hey, I looked through the examples, and I think you have to use `.path` per the example. In addition, you can't see them because you need to define a `width` and a `height` for network images. Please check my revised answer to see if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep you were right I forgot to set the width and height. It works perfectly thanks a lot u saved me a lot of time :)